# Define the mirrored vector of a given coord

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Not sure if the title made any sense, but hopefully the following overview of the exercise will thin the haziness. This is a 3-part exercise and I had no troubles with the first two. I'll briefly go over the exercise:

*Let L (line) be 2x - y = 3. Define the coordinate on L that's the closest to the coord (6, -1). Also define the distance between that of L and (6, -1).* **ALSO define the mirror of (6, -1) in L.**

The items that are in cursive I have already managed to solve, the bold part is what I am struggling with. I'll post my attempt below and also the, what I think are, pre-requisites in-order to complete the exercise.

The normal vector is : $ 2 \choose -1  $
L's normal: $ 6 \choose -1  $   -    t$ 2 \choose -1  $
This gives us $t  = - 2 $
The distance is thus $|-2n| = \sqrt{-2^2} \sqrt {2^2 - 1^2 } = 2 \sqrt { 5 } $

I plug t ( - 2) into L's normal and get
$  6 \choose -1  $ $-$  $ 2$$ 2 \choose -1 $ $ = $ $2 \choose 1$  which we could call Q, this is the coordinate that is the closest to (6, -1)

This is where I am stuck. I know that the formula is $ v - 2v' $ to get the mirrored vector, but I just don't know. I know I need to find the vector for (6 -1), alas, I am unsure how to do this. Also, is 'v' the vector of L in this formula? (which I did forget to add, but it's $ 1 \choose 2 $
(obviously , as the normal $ \bullet $ v $ = 0$))

So in short, I am having troubles finding the vector for Q. I thought it would be
$ 2 \choose 1 $ - $ 6 \choose - 1 $ $ = $ $ -4 \choose 2 $ but then, according to the formula (  $ v - 2v' $ ), I'd get $ 1 \choose 2$ - 2$-4\choose 2$ $ = $  $ 9 \choose 2 $ HOWEVER, the answer should be $ -2\choose 3$

What I can say, however, is that both the distance AND the coord that is closest to (6, -1) are correct!

I hope this is enough, but please do let me know if you find this information insufficient!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the mirror, now that you have the closest point $Q = (2,1)$ to $P=(6,-1)$ on $L$, you just need to move from the closest point $Q$ as much as $Q-P$. So the mirror would be $ Q+(Q-P) = 2Q-P = (-2,3)$.

Comment: Of course! This makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much